# Using DLOOKUP with Formatdate

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'm trying to use dlookup to see if a date is already in a table, the format is correct as I've checked and it inputs it correctly, just can't get it right for DLOOKUP.

```
Datelookup = DLOOKUP ("[todays_date]", "119_review", "[todays_date] = Format ("" & Me.Combo87 & " " & Me.Combo89 &" 20" & Me.Combo91 & "", medium)")
```

Combo87 is the day of the month
Combo89 is the month
Combo91 is the last 2 digits of the year

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
Datelookup = DLookup("[todays_date]", "119_review", "[todays_date] = DateSerial(" & Me.Combo91 & ", " & Me.Combo89 & ", " & Me.Combo87 & ")")
```

where *DateLookup* will be Null for "not found".

And do rename your controls to something meaningful.

Comment: I ended up using  

`code`If DLookup("[todays_date]", "119_review", "[todays_date] = #" & Format("" & Me.Combo87 & " " & Me.Combo89 & " 20" & Me.Combo91 & "", Medium) & "#") > 0 Then `code`

which works for me, it's searching the table and finding if the date is already in the table.

Comment: when i run debug the immediate window show `code UPDATE 119_review SET Earned_Income=262 AND Earned_income_withcal=258.4 WHERE [todays_date]=9/13/2017; ` but it's not updating the table at all, which I'm thinking is because the date is in the table as 13-Sep-17 and not 9/13/2017

Comment: Use the answer provided. It works - as the criteria will read `"[todays_date] = DateSerial(17, 9, 13)"`.

Comment: That worked for me, sorry it’s been a minute since I’ve been on SO.

Comment: Thanks. Never too late. Then please mark as answered.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Sub DL()
    Dim d As Date
        d = DateSerial(Me.Combo91.Value, Me.Combo89.Value, Me.Combo87.Value)
    Datelookup = DLookup("[todays_date]", "119_review", "[todays_date] = #" & Format(d, "Medium") & "#")
End Sub
```

Comment: Type mismatch. Would that be because the year is only showing the last 2 digits? So it's putting 17 and not 2017.

Comment: Try now, had the date parts (year, month, date) incorrect. The 2 digit year are added automatically but you may need to format the date as "mm/dd/yyyy".